# How can I parse out of the last instance of text after a delimiter (big query)

Tags: google-bigquery, substring, delimiter

Ex of value: [{‘test’:’https://‘,’id’,’2521’,’Shipment’}]

I would only want to return Shipment as the value returned for that field

Comment: Could you please include what you have already tried? Maybe specify what areas you need help with as there are a few pieces to this puzzle :)

Comment: My field name is called component. I have tried the following: select split(component,”’”) — when I try that though it yields multiple results. I only need the last instance

Comment: is this a string? do you really have `[{` and `}]` as a part of string or this is something else?

Comment: Yes it is a string and those characters are a part of it

Comment: I needed up figuring it out. Here is the code that worked: SPLIT(components, “‘“)[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(components, “‘“)) - 2)]

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```sql
SPLIT(components, "'")[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(components, "'")) - 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below instead

```
array_reverse(split(translate(components, '[]{}', '')))[offset(0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid unnecessary arrays and use substr/insrt whenever possible

```
select substr(components, instr(components, "’", -1, 2) + 1, instr(components, "’", -1, 1) - instr(components, "’", -1, 2) - 1)
from (select "[{‘test’:’https://‘,’id’,’2521’,’Shipment’}]" components)
```